# AngularJS check image for 404 and get dynamic URL for image src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my repeater:

```
<div ng-click="selected(entity)" ng-if="entity.is_organization == true">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell info">
            <span class="text" ng-bind-html="entity.label"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell img" ng-show="isImageAvailable">
            <img class="image" ng-src="checkImageAvailable(entity.thumbnail[0])">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`checkImageAvailable` in the controller:

```
$scope.isImageAvailable = false;
$scope.checkImageAvailable = function(image_url){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function (){
    $scope.isImageAvailable = true;
  };
  img.onerror = function (){
    $scope.isImageAvailable = false;
  };
  img.src = image_url;
  if($scope.isImageAvailable){
     return image_url;
  }
};
```

I get the `entity.thumbnail[0]` from the JSON, but even it has a URL it doesnt exist. So I do check it using `checkImageAvailable`. If image is not available, set `isImageAvailable` set to false, so image parent container `ng-show` is taken care to hide the image placeholder from browser.
Same time on the console log it shows:
`http://localhost/checkImageAvailable(entity.thumbnail[0])` is `404`

What may be the mistake I'm doing in front of AngularJS.

Comment: `onload` is asynchronous so your function will never return the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that's wrong is that by the time you set:

```
$scope.isImageAvailable = true; //or false
```

you're outside the angular lifecycle - so you have to call `$scope.$apply()`;

Any time you make changes to the angular scope outside of an angular event, you have to call `$apply()`.

Checking isImageAvailable will probably be false as `onerror/onload` will be called back asynchronously so you could just return `image_url` right away.

**Edit**

So it turns out that you would have to call the method like:

```
ng-src="{{checkImageAvailable(entity.thumbnail[0])}}"
```

But there's a problem because angular keeps calling the method in a loop. 
Even if you do:

```
ng-src="{{::checkImageAvailable(entity.thumbnail[0])}}"
```

it still gets called 3 times. I don't know why 3.

So at this point I would try with a different approach: custom directive. When it initializes you set the image as hidden, attach the onload/onerror handlers to the element and then depending on which gets called, you show the image or not.

Let me know if it doesn't make sense.
Demo: http://jsbin.com/yenipodimi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.isImageAvailable = true; // or false;
});
Is that what you mean by?

Comment: You can do it like that, or just call $scope.$apply(). I created a jsbin example .. but for some reason it calls the new image over and over